# Hash won't match to dictionary when hashed with SHA512. What am I missing?

Tags: python, hash, sha512

I'm trying to crack an SHA512 hash by matching it to a dictionary using python. However, I cannot get the hash to match any of the words.

I think the issue is with the salt and dictionary words being incorrectly inputted to `hashlib.sha512()`:

I have split out the hash with `shadow.split(":")[1]` however I cannot correctly parse down from here, I have tried splitting on `"$"` to seperate the password and salt in addtion to blindly splitting on `"."` and `"/"` to no avail.

My code:

```
#! usr/bin/python

import hashlib

dictionary = ["apple", "orange", "egg", "lemon", "grapes", "secret", "strawberry", "password"]

shadow = "root:$6$ms32yIGN$NyXj0YofkK14MpRwFHvXQW0yvUid.slJtgxHE2EuQqgD74S/GaGGs5VCnqeC.bS0MzTf/EFS3uspQMNeepIAc.:15503:0:99999:7:::"

def testPass(cryptPass):
    for word in dictionary:
        salt = cryptPass.split("$")[2]
        cryptWord = hashlib.sha512(salt + word).hexdigest()
        print("\nhashing word: '" + word + "'' with salt: '" + salt + "' -> " + cryptWord)
        if cryptWord == cryptPass :
            print("[+] Found Password: " + word + "\n")
            return
    print("[-] Password Not Found.\n")


def main():
        user = shadow.split(":")[0]
        cryptPass = shadow.split(":")[1]
        print("Cracking password for:" + user)
        print("Hashed Password: " + cryptPass)
        testPass(cryptPass)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is a challenge in the textbook Violent Python by TJ O'Connor (p23)

Comment: It's a good idea to be clear on terminology: "encryption" and "hashing" are different things, and "encrypted with SHA512" doesn't make sense. Also, rather than "blindly" guessing where to split this string, you could try researching the format hashes are commonly stored in, and parsing it based on that; it's sometimes called "crypt format".

Comment: `if cryptWord == cryptPass :` should be `if cryptWord == cryptPass.split("$")[3] :`

Answer (score 1):

If i understand right the You are trying to Break Linux shadow password by brute force. which use `sha512` at it's core but this is not the end of story. In order to make hashed password more resistant to brute force attacks Linux use another implementation something like `Scrypt` or `PBKDF2` (not sure what implementation exactly does recent Linux versions use for `$6$`). They in essence try to hash password several times to make brute force more time consuming and CPU intensive. So, hashing with `sha512` wont result in same password hash as one saved in Linux shadow file. You can use a library like `crypt` which you pass to it password, salt and algorithm needed as:

```
import crypt
password="hunter2"
hashing_scheme_with_salt="$6$ABCD1234$"
res = crypt.crypt(password, hashing_scheme_with_salt)
print(res)
# split and compare here
```

which will use the Needed algorithm that Linux use.

EDIT: Linux use `crypt` function and default to `5000` round for sha256 and sha512 since glibc 2.7 according to the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html)

Comment: [Here](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) is the specification in case OP wants to do things the hard way and implement himself with nothing but `hashlib`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have made the suggested changes, and now the hashed dictionary words are in the right format but none of them match the hash in shadow. Therefore I am assuming either the real password is not in the dictionary or the password has been hashed multiple times? Since I can't match all words (it would take too long) and I don't know what other algorithm(s) have been used to hash then I cannot crack the password?

Comment: @kerosene did You use the ```crypt``` library mentioned in the answer if yes and that your code is actually working correctly then the password is not in the dictionary (This password is supposed to be your root password and not your normal user login password since both are different users so different passwords). second, Edit your question with the new code used.

Comment: @kerosene If you forget Your root password then I'm afraid there is no way to recover it (at least an easy way). To know if your normal user password is same as root password execute in terminal some command requiring a root privilege like ```sudo ls``` then enter root password if wrong it will till you